# bios configuration and efi partition

Tags: kernel, bios

sorry if this is a pain in the backside to answer but i have 2 questions here. First of all, i have an f552E asus amd 64 laptop with 18.4.2 ubuntu lts. 4gb ram 250gb rpm hd. I don't believe ubuntu was installed properly. I just spoke to asus on the phone and their advising i take my laptop into their service centre....where they usually ask you to part with a kidney or a lung as payment and on an old laptop like this its simply not worth it.

1st question: how can i get my bios (my bios version is current. Vers 202) to boot off a usb flash drive in order for me to re install ubuntu?

2nd question: how can i make sure that grub is installed on efi partition?

Comment: *I don't believe ubuntu was installed properly* Why? What's the actual problem? Perhaps it would have been a good idea to start with that or only ask about that?

Comment: My apologies, your right. However, i created a bootable usb and re installed ubuntu from scratch. I am happy with the outcome because it runs a lot more smoothly, my system is fully encrypted and although i cannot explain exactly how ubuntu was installed originally, this re install seems to have filled in the gaps in a weird way. Because i am new to ubuntu its hard for me to explain with the correct terminology. Thank you for your support, hopefully my next question is more straight forward...which it should be